# Error to Import Github project into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, import

I am trying to import Github [Project](https://github.com/michaelisvy/hibernate-4-spring-3.1-samples)  into my eclipse by Egit and used the URI,Host etc as you can check in Screen shot  and when i am giving my github userId/Password i am getting error see attached screen shot [image: GitHubExceptin] or this exception.

```
 https://github.com:22/michaelisvy/hibernate-4-spring-3.1-samples: cannot open git-upload-pack:
https://github.com:22/michaelisvy/hibernate-4-spring-3.1-samples: cannot open git-upload-pack
```

Is i am doing something wrong ? Or we can not import someone else project like this?
 [image: Git Values]

Comment: good question. i'm also facing this issue

Comment: I am also getting the same error. But the solution suggested didn't worked. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove ":22" add .git to your repo path ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it command prompt.

```
git clone git@github.com:michaelisvy/hibernate-4-spring-3.1-samples.git
cd hibernate-4-spring-3.1-samples
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

this is for eclipse.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github

Comment: @himansu i already done it but what is the use of EGit if we can not do this with Eclipse Like we did for SVN or CVS.